# Fluid Horizontal NavBar for responsive website

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, navbar, fluid-layout

Im trying to make a fluid responsive web that contains an horizontal navbar, my problem is that at a certain width of the browser window the elements of the bar start to relocate one on top each other, is there any way to avoid this behavior in order to make the navbar just stretch until a certain media query break point. I need to website to look al least decent in the ranges where the querys are not activated.

Here's how things look so far:
http://wearehellyeah.com/test/home_formacio.html

```
<div class="barra">
            <!--Menu Principal-->
            <nav class="menu-principal">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="item sub"><button type="button" id="menu-lateral" class="sb-toggle-left"><img src="img/iconos/menu.png" alt="search"></button></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Actualitat</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Activitat de l'oficina</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Vocalies</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Formació</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Serveis</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#">Actualitat</a></li>
                    <li class="item no-border"><a href="#" class="no-border">El Col-legi</a></li>
                    <li class="item home"><a href="#" class="no-border">Marcar com pàgina d'inici</a></li>
                    <li class="item conectados">Conectados 103</li>
                    <li class="item"><button type="button" id="search"><img src="img/iconos/search.png"></button></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!--Fin Menu Principal-->
            <!--Input buscador-->
            <div class="buscador">
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text" id="ip-search">
                </form>
            </div>
            <!--Fin de Input Buscador-->
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.barra {
background: #00b1da;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
}

.menu-principal {
height: 36px;
line-height: 35px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1024px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.menu {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.menu .item {
float: left;
list-style: none;
}

.menu .item a {
border-right: 1px solid #008ba9;
color: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 0 .98em;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu .sub {
background: #008ba9;
padding: 0 .4em;
height: 35px;
display: block;
}

.conectados {
background: #fff;
color: #4b585b;
font-size: 13px;
padding: .1em 1em 0 2.3em;
position: relative;
}

.menu .home {
background: url("../img/iconos/home.png") no-repeat 2% #00a9a1;
border-left: 1px solid #40c2d3;
padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a min-width:

```
.menu-principal {
    min-width:883px;
}
```

Then it won't go on top of each other. However there are too many options on the navigation bar, you might want to make it a drop-down box when it goes into a mobile media-query range.
e.g. http://vagish.com (as you make the browser width smaller, it changes the navigation bar)

You could have a media query which takes place between 768px and 880px, and reduces the spacing between menu items, and this should be able to make it look fine until you hit the 768px media query.

This would work (along with the CSS above):

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 880px) {
    .menu-principal {
        padding:0px;
    }
    .menu-med .item a {
        padding:0 .69em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vagish i will try that, the thing is i have only two designs for responsive: One for mobile (320px) where i have another navbar just with tab buttons and the other one for tables (768px) but what im trying to do is for the navbar to stay the same until it hits the 768px break where i activate my media query and change the navbar to a smaller one. My responsive approach is to make this looks pretty decent at any point you are resizing the browser window, the same thing you are doing on your website actually. Any other ideas will be REALLY appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more CSS code, and this should solve your issue.

Comment: i got you @Vagish so the trick is to reduce the padding within the navbar everytime the window resize to a point where the navbar elements will go on top of each other right ? i will explore into your technic and will let you know, thanks a lot !

Comment: Pretty much, just get something like Firebug (Firefox plugin) or use Inspect Element on Chrome and keep modifying the CSS. That's how I do it. Also if I've answered your question you can press the green tick next to my answer. :)

Comment: sorry to bother you again @Vagish. After been playing with this method i start to feel like i have to make a media query every time the browser window stretch in like 10px because everytime the window resize at one point the navbar will again put one element on top of each other. Is there any way to make relative paddings in order to not change them every time the window resize and break the navbar ?

Comment: You just need to make one change really. You don't need to change it every 10px.

Comment: Got it @Vagish ! thakns